# Remove product dimensions from single product pages in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product, dimensions

Anyone knows how to hide the product dimensions from the additional tabs on Single Product page but still show the Weight value?

I search and see this filter but it hides both weight and dimensions.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_dimensions', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: try to do it with  custom CSS

Comment: Hi, the css of this row is 

<tr>
   <th>Dimensions</th>
   <td class="product_dimensions">156 x 56 x 16 cm</td>
  </tr>
I can hide the td with has class. But Don't know how to hide these tr

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can you update your answer by posting the whole CSS of your product?

Comment: I have used Overriding Woocommerce templates and now it works. Thank you for your help :) @IvnH

Comment: I have an answer for [your deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65441945/3730754)… If you like you can re-publish it back and I will answer it (notify me here if it is the case).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec For that Question, I have tried in many ways and it doesn't work. Then, I figure out that it happens because The Third Payment Plugin for WooCommerce is to override the stock status for reducing only Order status is "Processing". If you have any suggestion, it will be so kind for this situation. I have re-publish already. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To hide only dimensions** *(but not weight)*, there is **2 ways** to make it work.

**1) using hooks** *(here composite filter hooks*):

Looking at the template that displays dimension in single products, you can see this line:

```
<?php if ( $display_dimensions && $product->has_dimensions() ) : ?>
```

Then if you look at [`WC_Product` `has_dimensions()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1484-1491), you will see this line *(where `$this` is the `WC_Product` Object instance)*:

```
return ( $this->get_length() || $this->get_height() || $this->get_width() ) && ! $this->get_virtual();
```

So when the length, the height and the with are empty (or false), the method returns false…

The following code that use **composite hooks**, will hide **dimensions** from "Additional information" tab in single product pages only:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_width', 'hide_single_product_dimentions', 25, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_height', 'hide_single_product_dimentions', 25, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_length', 'hide_single_product_dimentions', 25, 2 );
function hide_single_product_dimentions( $value, $product ){
    // Only on single product pages
    if( is_product() )
        $value = '';

    return $value;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.

> **To hide weight** *(just for info)* use this composite hook code:
>
> ```
> add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight', 'hide_single_product_weight', 25, 2 );
>   function hide_single_product_weight( $value, $product ){
>     // Only on single product pages
>     if( is_product() )
>         $value = '';
>
>     return $value;
> }
> ```

---

**2) Overriding Woocommerce templates**  via your active theme:

First read: [Overriding Woocommerce template via the theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

It explain how to copy the template to your theme before editing it.

Here the related template is [`single-product/product-attributes.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.4/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php).

You will have to remove this block from the template code (from line 33 to line 38):

```
<?php if ( $display_dimensions && $product->has_dimensions() ) : ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php _e( 'Dimensions', 'woocommerce' ) ?></th>
        <td class="product_dimensions"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_dimensions( $product->get_dimensions( false ) ) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It shows
Dimensions .  N/A

How can we remove this tr row?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/FgK56yx

The codes you give me is remove the dimension but how to remove this all row?

Comment: @phraisohn It should not as if dimensions are not defined (which is the case if you use my code), it doesn't display anything related to dimensions. I think that your theme is overriding woocommerce templates and may be the template `single-product/product-attributes.php` is outdated … You can check that in Woocommerce > Status going at the end of the page in "Template overrides" section.

Comment: Yes. the template is outdated and maybe because I create the New custom dimension to display in conditional tab too. That's why it shows both dimensions of my products. So, I want to hide the main original dimension which comes with WooCommerce in the Single page but still need to use to calculate the shipping price. Maybe  I will use CSS to hide this row to see if it work.

Comment: Updated. Yes, I remove the code in that template file and it works as I need. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the css property `display:none` if everything else fails.