# WooCommerce - remove dimensions EVERYWHERE on frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I googled, searched and found only one piece of code that helped to hide dimensions, including weight - [Remove product dimensions from single product pages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199913/remove-product-dimensions-from-single-product-pages-in-woocommerce)

But the thing I couldn't figure out is, how to remove it everywhere on my frontend, even on the products list, etc...

Is there any way for it, or it's possible only for single product page? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an exemple of website with woocommerce ?

Comment: https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/shop/

Answer (score 0):

With css :

```
.product_dimensions {
    display:none;
}
```

Or open your text file and edit your template file, to remove : product_dimensions

Comment: I know about this, but when using this method, it won't be replaced by another attribute, there will be just blank space.