# Remove "Weight" from admin product settings and single product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, backend

I work on small business site, and have a hard time to remove weight from product backend, and also from single product page into "Additional Informations" page. I tryed all "working" solutions that I found on web like [Remove product dimensions from single product pages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199913/remove-product-dimensions-from-single-product-pages-in-woocommerce/52200181#52200181) answer code and this code too:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight' , '__return_false' );
```

But it seems like that not makes any changes. For better to explain what I need to remove:

[image]

[image]

Tryed also with CSS:

```
.tabs-layout-tabs #tab-additional_information .shop_attributes
{
display:none;
}
```

But this remove all data from the tab. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will hide weight field from product backend shipping setting section:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'hide_weight_field_from_product_shipping_setting_section', 100 );
function hide_weight_field_from_product_shipping_setting_section() {
    ?>
    <style>
    p.form-field._weight_field  {
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

---

Now for frontend single product pages, the code below (like in your question) works on last WooCommerce version, removing weight row from "Additional information" tab:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight' , '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: First code works perfectly, but second one: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_weight' , '__return_false' );
`

Is hidding entire tab from single product. Can hide just weight information instead removing entire tab?

Comment: @DrMTR It hides entire tab if product dimensions are not set and/or product attribute for display… Otherwise it just removes the weight… Everything is tested on last woocommerce version. So the last code snippet work perfectly (tested on Storefront theme). If you have an issue, it will be related to some other customization made by you, your theme or a plugin. Please note that on StackOverFlow the rule is one question at the time.

Comment: @DrMTR I hope that you will find out the guilty, that is causing that issue for frontend single product pages.